# Expression won't run as it should

Tags: javascript, regex

I need an expression that will match with any number that may or may not have a + or - before it and also may or may not have a decimal at any before or after any number. .432423 and 42343242. is valid but a single decimal is not, even though with the expression I am running a single decimal is passing my validity test.  Please tell me what is wrong with this code rather than giving me an answer.  Thank you!

```
var number = /^((\-|\+)?([\d*\.?\d+])|([\d+\.?\d*]))$/;
```

Comment: Are you trying to capture parts of the number or just to verify whether the number conforms to certain format? You are using a lot of _parenthesis_ which means group capture in regex for extracting parts of the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[\d*\.?\d+]` matches any one character from that set, and so will match a single `.`. Removing both pairs of brackets makes it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

look at this one

> `/^([-+]?[.]{1}\d+)|([-+]?\d+[.]{1}\d*)$/`

with this one you have 2 match groups.. first give you numbers [+-].1234 
and second one [+-]123.[123]

Comment: @JohnCarpenter yep, and I think that was intention of question owner, and if not, its only metter of changing {1} to ? after [.]  if he wants integers

Comment: Hmmm, I think he wanted an optional decimal.  Either way, good point.  I'll delete my comment.